# How would i convert a comma seperated list to a square bracket array

Tags: php

I have this variable `$csv = '3,6,7,8';` that i need to convert to a square bracketed array of the form `$csv_array = [3,6,7,8];`

If i explode the csv like `$new_array=explode(",",$csv);`,it does not give me the array i want.

This is a running example http://3v4l.org/kYC0g

The code

```
$csv = '3,6,7,8';
$new_csv = '['.$csv.']';

if(is_array($new_csv)){
echo 'true';
}
else{
echo 'false';
//this is false
}

echo '<br/>';
$new_array=explode(",",$csv);

print_r($new_array);
//not what i am looking for

echo '<br/>';

print_r($new_csv);

echo '<br/>';

echo $new_csv;
```

Comment: The two 'types' of array are exactly the same in PHP. If you are looking for `JSON`, look at the answer by @Zanderwar

Comment: explode is giving the correct output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by a fellow stacker

> [RichardBernards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1857053/richardbernards) - The two 'types' of array are exactly the same in PHP. If you are looking for JSON

An example of using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to achieve what it is you require:

To **encode**:

```
$csv = '3,6,7,8';
$array = explode(",", $csv);
$json = json_encode($array);

echo $json;
```

To **decode** `$csv` into the normal array you provided it:

```
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($decoded);
```

And then to return it to its **original** format:

```
$csv = implode(',', $decoded);
```

See [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) for more information, and also see it's opposite [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode)

Keep in mind that JSON is literally a string and is not compatible associatively in PHP until it is decoded using the `json_decode()` function mentioned above. With that being said, replacing `true` with `false` in the example above would create an object array and multi-dimensional arrays would require them to be referenced differently, e.g. `$array->result`.

It would also be worth bringing to your attention the beauty of the predefined [CSV functions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp) within PHP

Comment: Now $json is a json string and not a php array.

Comment: Updated post to include that note. OP still marked off on answer none-the-less

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[` and `]` to string does not makes it PHP array.

```
$csv = '3,6,7,8';
var_dump(explode(',', $csv));

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "8"
}
```

That is equal to `["3", "6", "7", "8"]` as PHP array.

To get JSON array form it, use `json_encode(explode(',', $csv))`. Or simply `$jsonArray = "[{$csv}]"` if you need JSON array (not PHP array, because it will be simple string).